# How do I install psycopg2 for multiple python interpreters on a CentOS box?

Tags: postgresql, python, centos5

I have a CentOS 5.5 box, which comes preloaded with Python 2.4. I wanted 2.6, so used `yum`to get it from the EPEL repository. I also used `yum` to install the psycopg2 package, but it installed it for Python 2.4.

I tried copying `/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/psycopg2/` to `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/`, and when I ran my script, it worked... but it gave me a warning that said

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:69: RuntimeWarning: Python C API version mismatch for module _psycopg: This Python has API version 1013, module _psycopg has version 1012.
```

So it looks like there's some kind of versioning issue going on here, and I'm wondering what the best way to fix it is. Should I just ignore the warning and carry on? Is there a way to use `yum` to install psycopg2 for Python 2.6? Should I just [install from source](http://initd.org/psycopg/install/) using `python26 setup.py install`? I know installing from source is [generally a no-no in CentOS](http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=14408&forum=47), so I want this to be a last resort, unless it's the only option. I just don't want to mess up `yum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried copying `/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/psycopg2/` to `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/`...

That is not supposed to work.

If you want `psycopg2` available to multiple python interpreters, you have a few options... I like [`virtualenv`](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html#installation) for juggling multiple python installations on a system.   This way you can have as many combinations of sandboxed module versions as you like.

If you just want to install `psycopg2` where the Python2.6 libraries are, then we need to clarify python interpreters... let's assume Python2.6 is installed in `/usr/bin/python26`.  I will assume you've satisfied the dependencies for `psycopg2` in your Python2.6 install... at this point, download the [psycopg2 tarball](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg2/), untar, `cd` into the extracted archive directory, and (as root) run `/usr/bin/python26 setup.py install`.  This will install `psycopg2` for Python2.6.

Comment: `yum deplist psycopg2` returned nothing, so I'm assuming it doesn't have any dependencies? In that case, I think I'll go with this option. I'll mark it as the answer once I get to it.

Comment: You need the python2.6 development libraries and `pg_config`, which is an auxiliary binary for PostgreSQL

Comment: OK I have python26-devel and python26-libs installed through yum, but yum can't find libpq-dev. The closest thing I can find is libpqxx-devel in the rpmforge repo. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Update: pg_config was in `postgresql-devel` in the CentOS Updates repo.

Comment: Another update: Make sure you have gcc installed as well for the pyscopg2 setup.py script. Don't know how I got this far for so long without it.